# clearinterval not working inside ngOnDestroy()

Tags: javascript, angular

My ngOndestroy is calling with other route navigation but it is not executing clearInterval inside the method. Where am I making it wrong? It is running in background while i am in other component.

```
timer:any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.timer= this.interval();
};

 ngOnDestroy(){
    clearInterval(this.timer);
   console.log("Inside Destroy");


 }

interval(){
  setInterval(()=>{
    this.getData();
  },20000)
}
 getData(){
   this.dataservice.getdata()
      .subscribe(users=>{
      this.datas=users;
      console.log(this.datas);
    })
 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to return the instance of the interval.

```
interval(){
  return setInterval(()=>{
    this.getData();
  },20000)
}
```

Comment: Thank you zgue and patryk. It worked for me. You guys are awesome. thank a ton.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are not returning any value to `timer`.

```
// you need to return interval identificator to be able to clear it later.
interval(){
  return setInterval(()=>{
    this.getData();
  },20000)
}
```